# iPhone: what is the delegate for following users in MGTwitter engine

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

Can you tell  (Twitter)
the delegates for following friend in twitter and **getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus** this for followers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enableUpdatesFor:` takes an `NSString` of the username. It's a method not a delegate.

Comment: hi MarkPowell,thank you, can tell me the method, which this getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus i am printing on console the followers,but i want to print the following users of my profile, can u tell how to do this